# Check with what object the method is triggered

Tags: java

I call this method in java:

```
private void updateDisplay()
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                        minutes.getDisplayValue();
    }
```

What triggers this method two times for hours and minutes:

```
public String getDisplayValue()
{ 
    if(value < 10) {
        return "0" + value;
    }
    else {
        return "" + value;
    }
}
```

My question is how can i check in `getDisplayValue` if the method is triggerd as minute or as hour? For example:

```
public String getDisplayValue()
    {   if(this == minutes){
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value;
        }
        else {
            return "" + value;
         }
       }
```

Entire code:

```
public class ClockDisplay
{
    private NumberDisplay hours;
    private NumberDisplay minutes;
    private String displayString;    // simulates the actual display

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor 
     * creates a new clock set at 00:00.
     */
    public ClockDisplay()
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor
     * creates a new clock set at the time specified by the 
     * parameters.
     */
    public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        setTime(hour, minute);
    }

    /**
     * This method should get called once every minute - it makes
     * the clock display go one minute forward.
     */
    public void timeTick()
    {
        minutes.increment();
        if(minutes.getValue() == 0) {  // it just rolled over!
            hours.increment();
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Set the time of the display to the specified hour and
     * minute.
     */
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours.setValue(hour);
        minutes.setValue(minute);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current time of this display in the format HH:MM.
     */
    public String getTime()
    {
        return displayString;
    }

    /**
     * Update the internal string that represents the display.
     */
    private void updateDisplay()
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                        minutes.getDisplayValue();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class NumberDisplay
{
    private int limit;
    private int value;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class NumberDisplay.
     * Set the limit at which the display rolls over.
     */
    public NumberDisplay(int rollOverLimit)
    {
        limit = rollOverLimit;
        value = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return the current value.
     */
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Return the display value (that is, the current value as a two-digit
     * String. If the value is less than ten, it will be padded with a leading
     * zero).
     */
    public String getDisplayValue()
    { 
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value;
        }
        else {
            return "" + value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of the display to the new specified value. If the new
     * value is less than zero or over the limit, do nothing.
     */
    public void setValue(int replacementValue)
    {
        if((replacementValue >= 0) && (replacementValue < limit)) {
            value = replacementValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increment the display value by one, rolling over to zero if the
     * limit is reached.
     */
    public void increment()
    {
        value = (value + 1) % limit;
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: What are `hours` and `minutes`?!

Comment: Can you add the entire code here? It will make life easy.

Comment: what are the hours there...? can u share your More understandable code to sort out the issue

Comment: Yes i added my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a parameter into `getDisplayValue()` function like this

```
getDisplayValue(char c)
```

and change your function definition to :

```
public String getDisplayValue(char c)
    {   
      if(c == 'h'){
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value;
        }
        else {
            return "" + value;
         }
      }
      else if(c=='m'){
            return value*60;
      }
    }
```

and change `updateDisplay()` to :

```
private void updateDisplay()
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue(h) + ":" + 
                        minutes.getDisplayValue(m);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it using *reflection* by checking the *stack trace*, see [`Thread#getStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Go through the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) and see what methods are useful for your needs.

But why don't you simply pass an identifier that allows you to detect who called the method?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a boolean parameter in the function declaration

```
public String getDisplayValue(Boolean isMinute)
{   
    if(isMinute)
    {
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value;
        }
        else {
           return "" + value;
        } 
    }
    else{
          // not a minute, continue
    } 
}
```

you can call this like

```
    displayString = hours.getDisplayValue(false) + ":" + 
                    minutes.getDisplayValue(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce 2 sub-classes

```
public class HourDisplay extends NumberDisplay {
    // override getDisplayValue method the way you want
}

public class MinuteDisplay extends NumberDisplay {
    // override getDisplayValue method the way you want
}
```

Then in ClockDisplay constructor

```
public ClockDisplay()
{
    hours = new HourDisplay(24);
    minutes = new MinuteDisplay(60);
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, I wanted to give a comment but don't know how to do it on the question, I'm new :)

Answer (score 0):

i will added a `boolean` flag in `ClockDisplay` i.e. `isHour`. And will change the constructure:

```
class ClockDisplay{
    boolean isHour;
    public ClockDisplay(boolean isHour)
        {
            hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
            minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
            updateDisplay();
            this.isHour=isHour;
        }
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

Now in `NumberDisplay` i will change the method:

```
public String getDisplayValue(ClockDisplay c)
    { 
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value;
        }
        else {
            return "" + value;
        }
    c.
    }
```

Now inside the method `getDisplayValue()` you can call any method on top of `c`, and it can print accordingly because you have set `isHour` accordingly.

**The reason behind my design is: The abstraction whether `hour` or `minute` it should be encapsulated inside `ClockDisplay`. So just pass the `ClockDisplay` reference to `getDisplayValue()`.**